# Is there a way to trust something in the Bot Framework Skype for Business ChannelData to be certain that a user is from a given domain?

Tags: botframework

I want to only serve users from within a tenant, even if the tenant is configured to talk to people from other domains. But I don't want to force the users to login as I don't need a token to do anything in the back end and that would add more friction to the usage.

So can I check for something in the request that I can be sure it can't be tampered with, so that no one from outside my tenant can talk to the bot?

Comment: You should 1st have a look in details in an activity content, to see what's provided. I don't remember which fields are provided in the case of Skype for Business, maybe you can add an example

Comment: I’m having issues to set up the bot in SfB but I want to debug that. I’ll update with any findings. The question though was more geared towards knowing if I can trust the data coming in there as it is from a bot framework pre built channel or if it could be tampered with by an attacker. I will want to make sure of this as well for other channels such as MS Teams and Slack.

Comment: Is there a specific location you are planning on adding this secret at the moment? Where are you trying to block messages from coming from? A direct post to a channel endpoint from a URL that was not set up with/by you?

Comment: I don’t want anyone from outside a given organization to be able to talk to the bot. It could be a user that doesn’t have an email from the company domain in Skype for Business. For example a SfB tenant that allows external users to contact company’s contacts....I don’t want external users to contact the bot.

Comment: Is there any reason adding some form of [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) linked to a company account to your bot wouldn't work in this case?

Comment: I don’t think so. I just want to avoid it if I don’t need authentication. Given that the user is already logged in to Skype for Business for example, if I can tell if that account is from a trusted domain the there’s no need for the user to go through the “hassle” of signing in

Comment: Can you describe the ingress/embed that users will use for the case where they aren't talking to it directly via Skype for Business itself (or some other channel) a bit more? Is it an embedded iframe from one of these sites?

Comment: Currently no other channel other than Skype, Teams or Slack. I’ll add authentication down the line because I’ll need to request permissions but I don’t want to do it now if the user doesn’t need it.